# Copy a line in the row directly above with Notepad++

Tags: regex, xml, row, notepad++, line

I have a large XML file and I need to copy a line in the row directly above with Notepad++ and RegEx (if it is possible, of course).

For example:

```
<text></text>
<reference>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</reference>
```

With a Regex I need to copy the content of "reference" line and paste above in the "text" line.

So this is the final result:

```
<text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</text>
<reference>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</reference>
```

Someone knows a simple solution for this problem?

Thanks to all in advance =)

Comment: It is not a difficult thing, but did you try anything? Please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it quick&dirty with Notepad++, then replace this pattern:

```
(<text>)(</text>\s+<reference>(.*?)</reference>)
```

With this:

```
$1$3$2
```

- `$1` is `<text>`
- `$2` is all the content from `</text>` to `</reference>`
- `$3` is the contents inside `<reference>`

`\s+` means *at least one whitespace*, and a newline is whitespace.

Comment: I works perfectly! Thanks for your explanation, I learned something more today =)

Answer (score 0):

How I would do about this is like this:
First I would delete all occurrences of

```
          <text><\text>
```

, provided you dont delete the occurrences you dont intend. And then in regular expression replace the occurrences of

```
           (.*)<reference>(.*)</reference>
```

by

```
           \1<text>\2</text>\r\n\1<reference>\2</reference>
```